# Restaurar base de datos Sql Server 15 en versión 13

Tags: sql

tengo una base de datos en Azure (Sql Server 2019 Versión 15) y necesito restaurarla en un 2016 Versión 13.
Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Este es el error que obtengo:
Msg 3169, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The database was backed up on a server running version 15.00.2000. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 14.00.2027. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Gracias!

Comment: Saludos. De ser posible te sugiero montar esa versión al menos de manera temporal o veas si hay alguna BD (de la versión del Backup) donde colocarlo temporalmente y extraerlo como Script SQL; así no importara la versión (sin embargo sí las funciones nueva de la versión 13 a la 15).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Si hay forma, hay un procedimiento que ya hice un avez y no encuentro en google nuevamente, pero si es posible

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro en lo que menciona. No se puede restaurar un respaldo creado en una versión más reciente de SQL Server. No hay ninguna forma de hacerlo y generando el script puedes terminar con un archivo inmenso o generar solo la estructura (que no es un respaldo).

La única opción real es actualizar la version 2016 a una versión 2019. De otra forma, es crear la estructura y copiar poco a poco la información (lo cual requiere de mucha planeación si hay integridad referencial).